# Ember App Kit 'validate-imports' task blows up when using coffee-script

Tags: ember-app-kit

I have renamed `app.js` to `app.coffee` (as well as translated the contents), but now when I compile I get this error:

```
Running "validate-imports:tests" (validate-imports) task
>> client/tests/helpers/start-app: Cannot find module "client/app"
```

This error goes away when I translate the file back to javascript.

I have added the `grunt-contrib-coffee` and confirmed it works correctly, the problem I believe is that the coffee-script compilation happens after the `validate-imports` task which looks for .js files in the app folder. Does this need to be tweaked to look in the `tmp/javascripts` folder where the coffee-script gets compiled to?

Here is the task in question:

```
  // Scripts
  grunt.registerTask('buildScripts', filterAvailable([
                     'jshint:app',
                     'jshint:tests',
                     'validate-imports:app',
                     'validate-imports:tests',
                     'coffee',
                     'emberscript',
                     'copy:javascriptToTmp',
                     'transpile',
                     'concat_sourcemap'
                     ]));
```

Anyone know of this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/issues/543). Thus, when I tried it, I renamed `start-app.js` to `start-app.coffee`, converted the code into coffescript and now it works without that error.

Bryan

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this would be to add this line to your testem.json file:

```
"before_tests": "coffee -c tests/**/*.coffee"
```

This should compile the .coffee files within your `/tests` directory before test execution, meaning they will compile down to their `.js` equivalent before they are run.  While you could technically change the EAK boilerplate from `.js` to `.coffee` with a similar trick, it might be better just to write your tests in `.coffee`, while leaving the default `.js` testing harness to maintain compatibility with EAK.

You can also remove these files when the test run is over, as shown within [the tapas-with-ember testem.json](https://github.com/mutewinter/tapas-with-ember/blob/master/testem.json#L5) file.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work consistently.  I'll update when I've got it working.